# File in use error after copying with WebClient to FTP

Tags: c#, webclient

I download a file from a local ftp, with this code:

```
System.Net.WebClient oClientFTP = new System.Net.WebClient();
oClientFTP.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password");
oClientFTP.DownloadFile("ftp://192.168.0.10/files/test.pdf","test.pdf");
oClientFTP.Dispose();
```

The file is copied correctly but is not released, anything I try to do tells me that the file is in use by another application. I tried using ProcessExplorer but it didn't solve the problem.
I also tried to copy the file to another file but the problem is the same.
How can I free the file after copying?

Comment: Use `using` instead of manually disposingg the file (`using var ftpClient = new WebClient()){ ...}`) to ensure the client is disposed even in case of error and *don't* use type prefixes. Everything in .NET is an object, so `o` means nothing.

Comment: In any case, it's far more likely that the file *is* in use - either it hasn't finished downloading, or another part of your code has opened it. `DownloadFile` doesn't keep the file open once it finishes. OTOH `ProcessExplorer but it didn't solve the problem.` that means *another process* has locked the file. File handles are owned by their processes. If you kill a process, all file handles created by it are killed. No exceptions. Perhaps an antivirus is inspecting the file? Or the wrong process was killed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using a stream which I then write to file.

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(oClientFTP.DownloadData(cFtp +cNomefile)))
{
  using (FileStream outputFileStream = new FileStream(cNomefile, FileMode.Create))
  {
    stream.CopyTo(outputFileStream); 
  }
}
```